# Sharing common code without using friend and ignoring include dependencies

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

### My question:

Is there any better way to do something like macro expansion. It feels like putting the code in the same file and working separately without using `friend` and not breaking encapsulation?

### Details:

I have two class. Two classes have exact the same function doing the same work and they have duplicate code in their source file. However they don't have common base class.

```cpp
class A{
public: 
    void run(){
        // In real code it has dependency to 10+ headers below. Just use vector as an example
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(0); // Something more complex here.
        instance.enable();
    }
protected:
    void enable(){
        std::cout<< "A enable" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class B{ //Same as A, but B and A have no common class.
};
```

I tried to refactor to pull the code together in one file while not touching much things. I tried not to use normal inheritance way to handle it, because I don't want to handle the include headers again since there are many headers.

Using this way, my refactored `Common.h` header doesn't need to take care of include dependencies since template would just copy/paste the code into two different classes.
Following is my result, but I **don't like `friend`**.

Side note: I know I could use inheritance like [this snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/4qq65h6Pa), but I want to discover if there is other ways to do it.
In my production code, I use inheritance to handle the refactor since not all people in my teams knows template well (neither do I).

For the brevity of my following examples, I remove `class B` since it's duplicate of `class A`

### ==== CRTP (Mixins like style) ====

This is the most nearest way I tried.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xvq7vrcYo)
Note: By using this way, it needs to handle dependencies in header since `Common` need to be inherited by `A` and `B`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Common.h
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
class Common {
public:
    virtual void runImpl(){
        enable();
        // In real code it has dependency to 10+ headers below. Just use vector as an example
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(0); 
    }
protected:
    virtual void enable() = 0;
};

class A: public Common<A>{
public: 
    void run(){
        runImpl();
    }
protected:
    void enable(){
        std::cout<< "A enable" << std::endl; 
    }
};
int main(){
    A a;
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

### ==== Another refactor by `std::fucntion`====

By removing the friend, I use dependency injection for `std::funciton`. However this way will cause the refactor has performance impact on runtime. I could use it because it's just a simple gui task.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ha4aj9rf9)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// Common.h
#include <vector>
namespace Common{
    void runImpl(std::function<void()> enableFunction){
        // In real code it has dependency to 10+ headers below. Just use vector as an example
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(0); // Something more complex here.
        enableFunction();
    }
}

// A.h + A.cpp
class A{
public: 
    void run(){
        auto enableFunc = std::bind(&A::enable, this);
        Common::runImpl(enableFunc);
    }
protected:
    void enable(){
        std::cout<< "A enable" << std::endl; 
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

### === Refactor with `friend` ===:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1oGYnTc6e)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Forward declaration
namespace Common{
template<class T>
    void freerun(T& instance);
}

// A.h + A.cpp
class A{
public: 
    template<class T>
    friend void Common::freerun(T& instance);
    void run(){
        Common::freerun(*this);
    }
protected:
    void enable(){
        std::cout<< "A enable" << std::endl; 
    }
};

// Common.h
#include <vector>
namespace Common{
template<class T>
    void freerun(T& instance){
        // In real code it has dependency to 10+ headers below. Just use vector as an example
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(0); // Something more complex here.
        instance.enable();
    }
}


int main(){
    A a;
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for sounds like a [*mixin*](https://dlang.org/spec/template-mixin.html).  C++ does not have mixins.

Comment: Wow, that might be the things I want to dig into. Thanks for the keyword! I thought template could do the same thing. It seems not at the moment.

Comment: Could you move the common code into a static method, either in one of these classes or a helper class?

Comment: @JosephLarson Could you elaborate on the difference between my [inheritance version](https://godbolt.org/z/4qq65h6Pa) and your suggestions? It seems like my version doesn't mark `runImpl()` as static. Since `enable()` is protected, the static method need to be in the `Common` class. Or marking it static would improve performance?

Comment: It may not be dramatically different. Another choice would be to make an include file (with no double-include protection and `#include` it in the right place. I don't like using `friend` either, and in this case, i would have inherited from a common subclass.

Comment: @JosephLarson, I tried with "mixins" taste by using template. However I think it requires to handle all the dependencies in the `Common.h` header.